# Magento 2 - why is my plugin for \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder not working?

Tags: magento2, extensions, plugin

I try to write an after plugin for the method `getItemOptions` of the class `\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder`

#### Attempt:

**app/code/Company/Configurator/etc/di.xml**

( I also tried **app/code/Company/Configurator/etc/frontend/di.xml** )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder">
        <plugin name="Company_Configurator_Plugin_Frontend_Magento_Sales_Block_Order_Email_Items_Order_DefaultOrder"
                type="Company\Configurator\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder"
                sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Company/Configurator/Plugin/Frontend/Magento/Sales/Block/Order/Email/Items/Order/DefaultOrder.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\Configurator\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order;

class DefaultOrder extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder
{
    public function afterGetItemOptions(
        \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        exit("test");
        return $result;
    }

}
```

But it is still calling the original Method and my exit is getting ignored.

---

- Im using Magento 2.4.2
- There is no other plugin for that class

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the `extends`.

**app/code/Company/Configurator/Plugin/Frontend/Magento/Sales/Block/Order/Email/Items/Order/DefaultOrder.php**

### Before:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\Configurator\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order;

class DefaultOrder extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder
{
    public function afterGetItemOptions(
        \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        exit("test");
        return $result;
    }

}
```

### After:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\Configurator\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order;

class DefaultOrder
{
    public function afterGetItemOptions(
        \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        exit("test");
        return $result;
    }

}
```